# PHP - How to get HTTP_REFERRER from Gmail?

Tags: http, hyperlink, gmail, referrer

When clicking links in Gmail emails it seems that Gmail isn't sending the HTTP_REFERRER. Is there another way to get the referrer for links clicked in Gmail?